# Multiple APK Rules..?

Tags: android, google-play, multiple-apk

I have build an android application using multiple apk files. I have followed the rules ie, unique version code, same package name, signed with the same certificate key, same apk file name. Now in order to distinguish for different screen resolution, I have written following codes in manifest file:

For 240x320:

```
<compatible-screens >
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/> 
</compatible-screen
```

For 320x480:

```
<compatible-screens >
   <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
</compatible-screens>
```

For 480x800:

```
<compatible-screens >
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
</compatible-screens>
```

For 720x1280:

```
<compatible-screens >
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>
</compatible-screens>
```

Please let me know if there is something wrong in this. Because if I am uploading multiple apk in google play, now when the user will download this application the appropriate apk should get download automatically . For eg if user is downloading this app using Google Nexus, then apk of 720x1280 should get downloaded.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK it is not a Good idea. Android has lots of different resolutions, and it is really very difficult  to

> **create a different APK for each resolution and also the make sure about user download the right apk.**

It'd be much better to just try to follow the [Developer Guide's advice](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html) in creating resources appropriate for a wide variety of screens.

Officially Written on above link :

> **Beware, however, that publishing multiple APKs for the same** 
>    **application is considered an advanced feature and most applications**
>    **should publish only one APK that can support a wide range of device**
>    **configurations.** Supporting multiple screen sizes, especially, is
>   within reason using a single APK, as long as you follow the guide to
>   Supporting Multiple Screens.

Best way is to provide drawables/layout for different resolutions rather than creating different apk depending upon resolutions. Universal application for all resolutions is best than different app for different resolutions.

[Read this for better understanding.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Hi Bhavesh +1 for ur response,i already go through developer site,what ever you told is correct only, but right now i cant change my applicaton,so please let me know what ever procedure i followed is correct or not..??.weather app will detected by different screen,as per as my Question..??

Comment: @KKC: Yes, Definitely it will work. but its not re-commanded. you can go ahead with it.